# Testing for specific numbers order for character and numbers in a string in java

Tags: java, string, string.format

Right what I was trying to do is validate some input so that the input must start with 2 letters and followed by 3 digits, but I can't find a way of testing a string for this

```
 boolean test;
 String str;
 str.format ("%s%s%d%d%d") //used this to give what the format was and was going to use it with a boolean, tried it in an if statement such as

if str.format = ("%s%s%d%d%d") then
{
 test = true
}
else
{
 test = false
}
```

I'm wondering what I would have to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a regular expression...

```
// Do this once and cache it...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}{2}\\d{3}");

// Then test it:
boolean test = pattern.matcher(str).lookingAt();
```

See the [`Pattern` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details (and alternatives to `\p{Alpha}`).

Comment: Rob wants this to match the start of the string, so you'd want to either add `.*` to the end of the pattern, or add `^` at the start and use `find()` instead of `matches()`.

Comment: @Nick: Whoops, thanks, fixed. (Just changed to use lookingAt, actually... that already checks that it's at the start of the string.)

Comment: Cool, I'd never noticed `lookingAt` before.